# .NET external configuration server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, configuration

I am developing a web application which will contain quite a few hosts. I have seen external configuration storages been used in Java e.g. with Spring Cloud Config Server.

Are there any non-custom alternatives in .NET? Currently, I am looking at the MSDN [External Configuration Store Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589803.aspx), and implementing it custom and re-using some of the code from that page.

Essentially, each node would have an initial configuration file (JSON) containing e.g. node name and url to DB where it will find other configuration parameters. Then I would have a separate service that can be queried by other services to return configuration data. It also caches config data locally.

There are some concerns with this:

1. how well it performs, i.e. configuration service may need to be scaled on multiple instances,
2. config data needs to be cached, and may even need a distributed cache for all config services to have a unified view of the cached config data,
3. this is custom implementation and will need maintenance,
4. how is config data changed, e.g. through a custom admin UI interface with CRUD operations?

Comment: I'm not I'm misinterpreting your situation, but have you looked into using `Puppet`? I've only ever used it for config files for load balancers in Linux environments, but from the looks of it could be used for Windows. It was a steep learning curve but made updating distributed config files very easy once everything was set up.

Comment: I use Ansible for managing server configurations, including custom app configs. The configuration is just a Yaml file. It manages multiple environments and is very flexible. Then I store all of the Ansible playbooks in Git and I have versioning. https://www.ansible.com/

Comment: Why is the Q closed ? I have the same problem. I don't want to use devops tools (puppet/ansilble) simply to update timeout on 27 machines. Some web-ui tool would be great for that. Reopen it